# What would be a good strategy for a 5tb database and index maintenance?

Tags: index, sql-server-2014

We use ollas index maintenance with some changes here and there done by our team.

we usually have an issue with a huge database where its Alter index locks some processes. Its normally a reorganize , even that it locks some tasks , like bulks for example.

what can we do to minimize this? nob is running for more than 24hrs every Sunday.

I thought in splitting tables, and do index maintenance in separated weekends.

I thought about an alert where it would kill the job of that locks for X minutes ( Bad since I'm aure it will never complete ).

Comment: What hardware is your system running on? SAN? Local Disks? (SSD, HDD, ....). What are the sizes of the tables of which the indexes are being reorganised? 50 GB, 100 GB, 200 GB? On average how much data or records are being added / modified per day? 2%, 10%, .... Is the data being archived in the productive tables? Put differently: does the data go back a long time? Add as much details as possible to your question by using the [edit] link. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be a good strategy for a 5tb database and index maintenance?

Don't do index maintenance.

What do you hope to achieve by doing it?

> Racer SQL: we expect to achieve performance by doing weekly index maintenance

It's a common misconception that index fragmentation is the root cause of one's performance problems and that index maintenance is the solution. Fragmentation is rarely the cause of performance issues. B-Trees are still highly effective within an index, even with huge amounts of fragmentation, especially nowadays when the disk is an SSD or NVMe. Fragmentation used to matter more on mechanical hard drives, but that's a thing of the past.

Some good side effects of index maintenance that *may* help improve performance is it invokes statistics to update for those indexes too. And it causes the plan cache to clear out any plans that relate to the tables of the indexes that were rebuilt. This is helpful for when a bad plan for certain queries accidentally gets cached. It'll cause the database engine to compile a new plan the next time that query runs, which may end up being more optimal.

The thing is, you can run each of these things separately, with more granularity, at a rate that's more conducive to your needs.

The other negative thing about index rebuilds (aside from resource contention, especially for larger indexes like you're using), is that it inflates the size of the database because it needs disk space to reorganize the data. And it creates a bunch of Transaction Log records as it's doing its work. Index maintenance is wasteful.

### Recap

1. Index Maintenance - Don't do it.
2. Update Statistics - Do it on a continuous routine for most things, at a rate that makes sense for your data and how often it changes.
3. Clearing the Plan Cache - Do it only occasionally and selectively for queries that tend to get stuck with poor plans

Comment: thanks for the response. it's rhe first time I hear this. we expect to achieve performance by doing weekly index maintenance. would you suggest doing it manually when issues/ bad performance is noticed ? or even a report of index stats,that when we see something bad, reorg/rebuild that specific table/index?

Comment: @RacerSQL Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @RacerSQL See for example Brent's advice about [not to care about index fragementation](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/). Spinning disk random IO slowness is so ... pre-SSD, pre x64 memory space.